# Can I refactor nested async.each loops?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, coffeescript

I'm writing a little cache warming tool in coffeescript. We have 2 target servers, 5 sites, 1000 pages per site, 3 versions per page. So a total of 30k requests to make. I'm using `async.each`, `async.eachLimit`, and `async.eachSeries` and it works beautifully. However, the code becomes a little challenging to read. I've looked at `async.waterfall` and promises, but that doesn't look like it'll help.

```
work = () ->
  async.each config.targets, (target, callback) ->
    async.eachLimit sitemaps, config.concurrency.sitemaps, (sitemap, callback) ->
      async.eachLimit sitemap, config.concurrency.urls, (url, callback) ->
        async.eachSeries config.requests, (req, callback) ->
          doRequest target, sitemap, url, req, callback
        , callback
      , callback
    , callback
  , (err) ->
      console.log "All done"
```

Is there some way I can rework this?

If the argument order was `async.each array, callback, iterator` I'd be happy with the layout above. But the syntax around the callbacks is a little difficult to read.

Comment: Namde functions don't inherit the scope, and there's no way to pass down variables with `async.each()`. So I don't think that approach would work. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: Not familiar with currying. Tried reading a bit, and I think I understand the basics. Not sure how it would apply here though. Can you give me an example?

Comment: This is probably a good candidate for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @Charlie Wasn't aware of Code Review, happy to move / have the question moved if you can do that. :-)

Comment: @chmac I would just post it there with a link back to here. You could also flag your own question to get a moderator's attention and see if they'll move it for you.

Answer (score 0):

How about splitting the function definitions onto their own lines?  I've also added parenthesis to make the function calls clearer (to me).

```
work = () ->
  async.each( config.targets, (target, callback) ->
    async.eachLimit( sitemaps, config.concurrency.sitemaps, 
      (sitemap, callback) ->
        async.eachLimit( sitemap, config.concurrency.urls, 
          (url, callback) ->
            async.eachSeries( config.requests, 
              (req, callback) ->
                doRequest( target, sitemap, url, req, callback)
            , callback)
        , callback)
      , callback)
  , (err) ->
      console.log "All done"
  )
```

EDIT

In theory one or more of the inner loops could be broken out as named functions.  For example:

```
foo1 = (sitemap, callback) ->
  async.eachLimit( sitemap, config.concurrency.urls,
    (url, callback) ->
      async.eachSeries( config.requests,
        (req, callback) ->
          doRequest( target, sitemap, url, req, callback)
      , callback)
  , callback)

work1 = () ->
  async.each( config.targets, (target, callback) ->
    async.eachLimit( sitemaps, config.concurrency.sitemaps,
      foo1
      , callback)
  , (err) ->
      console.log "All done"
  )
# error - target is not defined in doRequest(target...)
```

The problem here is that`target` as set by the `work1` loop, does not get passed through `foo1` to `doRequest`.

Looks like `async.apply` can be used to get around this problem

```
foo2 = (target, sitemap, callback) ->
  async.eachLimit( sitemap, config.concurrency.urls,
    (url, callback) ->
      async.eachSeries( config.requests,
        (req, callback) ->
          doRequest( target, sitemap, url, req, callback)
      , callback)
  , callback)

work2 = () ->
  async.each( config.targets, (target, callback) ->
    async.eachLimit( sitemaps, config.concurrency.sitemaps,
      async.apply(foo2, target)
      , callback)
  , (err) ->
      console.log "All done 2"
  )
```

Or carrying this partitioning to its extreme:

```
foo1 = (target, callback) ->
  async.eachLimit( sitemaps, config.concurrency.sitemaps
  , async.apply(foo2, target)
  , callback)

foo2 = (target, sitemap, callback) ->
  async.eachLimit( sitemap, config.concurrency.urls
  , async.apply(foo3, target, sitemap)
  , callback)

foo3 = (target, sitemap, url, callback) ->
  async.eachSeries( config.requests
  , async.apply(doRequest, target, sitemap, url)
  , callback)

work3 = () ->
  async.each(config.targets, foo1
  , (err) ->
    console.log "All done 3"
  )
```

Other binding/partial methods would work

```
foo2.bind(null, target) # Javascript bind
_.partial(foo2, target) # lodash, underscore
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I tried the second option, but the parent variables were undefined. Any suggestion on how to overcome that?

Comment: A binding/partial/curry method solves the undefined 'parent variables' problem.

Comment: Ooh, the `async.apply` looks interesting. That's definitely an interesting idea. Thanks. I don't fully understand what currying would look like or how `bind()` works, those are probably topics for another day. :-)

Comment: In this context `apply` creates a new function that does everything the original does, but also knows the value of `target`.  The Coffeescript `=>` does the same thing but with the current `@`.